# jQuery Mobile Navbar wrapping on 4 (not 5) elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working with the the jQuery Mobile and according to the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html) the navbar will wrap on five elements.  However, in my working with it, it's wrapping at only 4 elements.  Is this expected behavior?
    [image: Navbar from iPhone Simulator]

The code

```
<div data-role="page" id="images">

    <div data-role="header">    
        <h1><%= @disease.name %></h1>
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="plus" class="ui-btn-right">Add</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Images will be here.</p> 
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#images" class="ui-btn-active">Images</a></li>
                <li><a href="#symptoms">Symptoms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#treatments">Treatments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#notes">Notes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: What happens if you use shorter text?  Does it show all 4?

Comment: Can we see the css? either there is minimum padding keeping the elements from shrinking further, or the text is too long.

Comment: Shrinking the text was my first idea.  However, still didn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you're using the test site for documentation. Do you use the test CSS/JS as well or are you using jQM a4.1?

Using your code and jQM a4.1 it seems to work fine for me.

- Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dnqn9/1/
- Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/